# Whats the best way to convert this query into a Rails Activerecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello i'm looking to convert this query into an Active Record query on rails, can someone help?

```
SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id != '#{current_user.company_id}' ORDER BY CASE LOWER (premium_status) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, RAND()
```

Comment: what is `premium_status`?

Comment: premium_status is an integer being passed, if the integer is 1 then the company is premium or "featured", else its a free company.

Comment: so it's a field of `Companies` table?

Comment: yes its a field on the    companies table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think something else than that :

```
Company.where.not(id: current_user.company_id).order("premium_status = 1 DESC,rand()")
```

This code has been writter for Rails 4, what version are you using ?

Were you looking for something better ?

The premium companies will be at the top of the result, and it will be random after.

Comment: This is PERFECT, Thank you. This solves my answer. I would vote up but I don't have enough rep.